# Magento 2 override product list.phtml

Tags: magento2, phtml, product-list

I want to override product list.phtml and in my layout file catalog_category_veiw.xml i tried many methods but still not able to call my templates file

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list"  >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

I also tried this method

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
                    </action>
                </referenceBlock>
```

i also tried this

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Vendor_Modulename::product/list.phtml" />
```

I tried this all but not able to override, please help me to solve this and also tell me where i make mistakes, Thank you

Comment: you want to override or you want to change the block template?

Comment: i want to add some extra containt, calling Ajax

Comment: then you just need to override in your theme like vendor/theme/Magento_Product/templates/product/list.phtml

Comment: I am using default theme

Comment: then create custom module for that

Comment: Please check your file path or you can share here, please

Comment: Path of Which file

Answer (score 0):

To override in your module you can do something like this:

Create `etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="override_list_template" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
    </type>
</config>
```

In `Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;

class View
{
    public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject)
    {
        if ($template === 'Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml') {
            $subject->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml');
        }
    }
}
```

In `view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` put your override.

**Note** You should be able to just do this in your module:

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Vendor_Modulename::product/list.phtml" />
```